# Java Basic Memory Matching Game

Tags: java

I am trying to code a 4x4 memory matching game that has 8 identical number pairs. All face down cards are marked by an asterisk. Then the user inputs (1,1) and (1,2) as a guess and if correct they remain face up and the game continues.

My Problem: I have most of the code complete however my method *game* which runs the game I cannot figure out how to set it up. Any advice would be appreciated.

My Code:

```
     //Welcome Prompt
    System.out.println("Welcome to the memory matching game!");
    System.out.println("Enter the card coordinate for each card when promted to.");
    System.out.println("For Example, 11 = Card 1 and 12 = Card 2.\n\n");

    board();
}

//print the board
public static void board() {
    int[][] cards = new int[4][4];
    boolean upDown[][] = new boolean[4][4];

    cards = randomizer(); //Shuffle cards       
    System.out.println("     1 2 3 4 ");
    System.out.println("---+---------");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + (i + 1) + " | ");
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
            upDown[i][a] = false;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    game(upDown, cards); // calls the game
}

public static int[][] randomizer() {
    int num[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int cards[][] = new int[4][4];
    Random random = new Random();
    int temp, t;
    for (int j = 0; j <= 20; j++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) { //Randomize the card order
            t = random.nextInt(1000) % 15;
            temp = num[x];
            num[x] = num[t];
            num[t] = temp;

        }
        t = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) // Cards receive Numbers
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
                cards[r][s] = num[t];
                t = t + 1;
            }
        }

    }
    return cards;
}

//Start the Game
public static void game(boolean[][] upDown, int[][] cards) {

}

//shuffle the cards
public static int[][] shuf() {
    int start[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int cards[][] = new int[4][4];
    Random ran = new Random();
    int tmp, i;
    for (int s = 0; s <= 20; s++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) //randomize the card placements
        {
            i = ran.nextInt(100000) % 15;
            tmp = start[x];
            start[x] = start[i];
            start[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    i = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) // put values in cards here
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            cards[r][c] = start[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return cards;

}
}
```

Comment: Looks like a homework dump. Also, we're not here to write code for you. We just answer the questions about the code you've already written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic.  But it shows the basic idea of how to run the game.  Top left = "11", Bottom right = "44".  You can clean it up as an exercise (including static references are passed as method arguments, checking that input will not cause array out of bounds errors, etc)

```
public class MemoryGame {

    static int[][] cards = new int[4][4];
    static boolean upDown[][] = new boolean[4][4];
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setup();
        game(upDown, cards); // calls the game
    }

    //print the board
    public static void setup() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
                upDown[i][a]=false;
            }
        }
        cards = randomizer(); //Shuffle cards       
    }

    //print the board
    public static void displayBoard(boolean[][] upDown, int[][] cards) {

        System.out.println("     1 2 3 4 ");
        System.out.println("---+---------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + (i + 1) + " | ");
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
                if (upDown[i][a]) {
                    System.out.print(cards[i][a]);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[][] randomizer() {
        int num[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        int cards[][] = new int[4][4];
        Random random = new Random();
        int temp, t;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 20; j++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) { //Randomize the card order
                t = random.nextInt(1000) % 15;
                temp = num[x];
                num[x] = num[t];
                num[t] = temp;

            }
            t = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) // Cards receive Numbers
            {
                for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
                    cards[r][s] = num[t];
                    t = t + 1;
                }
            }

        }
        return cards;
    }

    //Start the Game
    public static void game(boolean[][] upDown, int[][] cards) {
        int noDownCards = 16;
        while (noDownCards > 0) {
            displayBoard(upDown, cards);
            System.out.println("Enter co-oridinate 1");
            String g1 = s.next();
            int g1x = Integer.valueOf(g1.substring(0, 1))-1;
            int g1y = Integer.valueOf(g1.substring(1, 2))-1;
            System.out.println(cards[g1x][g1y]);

            System.out.println("Enter co-oridinate 2");
            String g2 = s.next();
            int g2x = Integer.valueOf(g2.substring(0, 1))-1;
            int g2y = Integer.valueOf(g2.substring(1, 2))-1;
            System.out.println(cards[g2x][g2y]);
            if (cards[g1x][g1y] == cards[g2x][g2y]) {
                System.out.println("You found a match");
                upDown[g1x][g1y] = true;
                upDown[g2x][g2y] = true;
                noDownCards -= 2;
            }
        }
        displayBoard(upDown, cards);
        System.out.println("You win");
    }

    //shuffle the cards
    public static int[][] shuf() {
        int start[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        int cards[][] = new int[4][4];
        Random ran = new Random();
        int tmp, i;
        for (int s = 0; s <= 20; s++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) //randomize the card placements
            {
                i = ran.nextInt(100000) % 15;
                tmp = start[x];
                start[x] = start[i];
                start[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
        i = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) // put values in cards here
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                cards[r][c] = start[i];
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        return cards;

    }

}
```